# python sending udp packet - not always sent

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send a repetitive messages - one every 0.5 sec and other every sec.
When executing the code below, it is not running - I can't see it in wireshark.

Any idea how to sole it?

```
import socket 
import time

sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

LOCAL_IP = "1.1.1.1"
DST_IP1 = "224.1.1.1"
DST_PORT1 = 12345

DST_IP2 = "225.1.1.1"
DST_PORT2 = 22345

data1 = b'\x11\x22'
data1 = data1 + bytearray(30)

PERIOD = 500

Day=18


def updateTime(some inputs):
    some proccess
    
    return day

while True:
    Day = updateTime(Day)
    
    msg1=data1 + struct.pack('!B',Day)  
    msg2 = "some strings" + f'{Day:02d}' + "some more string"
    
    basetime = datetime.now()
    updated_time = datetime.now()
    D = updated_time - basetime
    
    while D.seconds < 1:
        sock1.sendto(msg1,(DST_IP1, int(DST_PORT1))
        time.sleep(int(PERIOD)/1000.0)
        updated_time = datetime.now()
        D = updated_time - basetime
    
    sock2.sendto(msg2,(DST_IP2, int(DST_PORT2))
```

Comment: UDP is not a reliable protocol. It does not have any retransmission, delivery guarantee, congestion control etc. as TCP does. I'm not sure if this explains what you are seeing, but nevertheless you should be aware that loss of packets is a legitimate situation, and if you are using UDP you need to design a protocol that handles it.

Comment: @jurez, the wireshark is taken on the source PC